# Unexpected animation behaviour in Handler.posthandler

Tags: java, android, animation

Here is my code

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.zoom_in);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            final int finalI = i;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
            optionImages[finalI].setImageResource(OptionArray[finalI]);
                    optionImages[finalI].startAnimation(animation);
                }
            },1000*i);
        }
```

there are four options (as OptionArray[4]). I want this options to appear one by one with a delay of 1 second and a zoom in animation.

The problem is each and every option animates when an option appears on screen. Like when option 2 appears with zoom in animation, option 1 again animates, after 1 second when option 3 appears with zoom in animation, option 1 and 2 again animates.

I want this animation just one time for each option.

I am a beginner and if title is not appropriate then please suggest and another one

Comment: call `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation` in a loop

Comment: thanks @pskink its totally working. Can you please tell me why it was not working.

Comment: I am really confused as how postDelayed work